# i can't display after i write the table into the file(Binary File)

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct Eleve {
    float note;
};

void saisirNote(struct Eleve E, FILE* fichedeNote, float T[30]) {
    char rep;
    fichedeNote = fopen("C:/Users/Ayoub/Desktop/TDTP/EX2/Notef/Fnote.dat", "wb");
    int i = 0;
    int en_desordre = 1;
    float tmp = 0.0;
    do {
        printf("\nSaisir Un Note %d: ", (i + 1));
        scanf("%f", &E.note);
        T[i] = E.note;
        i++;
        fwrite(&E, sizeof(&E), 1, fichedeNote);
        if (fwrite != 0)
            printf("\n\nSaisie de note avec Succes ! \n\n");
        printf("\n\nVoulez-Vous Saisir Un autre Note ?: ");
        scanf(" %c", &rep);
    } while (rep != 'N');

    for (int j = 0; j<i; j++) {
        printf("Note %d: %.2f\n", (j + 1), T[j]);
    }

    while (en_desordre == 1) {
        en_desordre = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j<i; j++) {
            if (T[j]>T[j + 1]) {
                tmp = T[j + 1];
                T[j + 1] = T[j];
                T[j] = tmp;
                en_desordre = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    while (fread(&E, sizeof(&E), 1, fichedeNote)) {
        for (int j = 0; j<i; j++) {
            E.note = T[j];
            fwrite(&E, sizeof(&E), 1, fichedeNote);
        }
    }
    printf("\n\n***Note Trie***\n\n");

    while (fread(&E, sizeof(&E), 1, fichedeNote)) {
        printf("\nNote = %f\n\n", E.note);
    }

}

int main()
{
    float T[30];
    FILE* fichedeNote;
    struct Eleve E;
    saisirNote(E, fichedeNote, T);
}
```

So basically the program is about to read Marks from the file and put it in a table then sore it ,  keep in mind it's (Binary File) , it looks i got an issue in Editing the record in the file but didn't figured out how to do it , hope you guys figure it out.

Comment: i don't see you closing the file handle with `fclose()`.  But what exactly is the problem?

Comment: `sizeof(&E)` ==> `sizeof E` is where i'd start.

Comment: You're trying to read from and write to the same file descriptor at the same time.  I don't think that's what you want to do.  Also, you need to check the return values of your functions.

Comment: i didn't close the file yet looks like i didn't explain well , the problem is that after editing the record in the file at while (fread(&E, sizeof(&E), 1, fichedeNote)) {
        for (int j = 0; j<i; j++) {
            E.note = T[j];
            fwrite(&E, sizeof(&E), 1, fichedeNote);
        }
and tried to edit it later it didn't display

Comment: Why are `E` and `fichedNote` parameters to the function? You never initialize them in the caller. They should just be local variables.

Comment: `if (fwrite != 0)` is not correct. You need to assign the preceding call to a variable, and test that.

Comment: If you want to read and write from the same file, you need to use `wb+` mode, not `wb`. And you need to use `fseek()` to go back to the beginning of the file before reading.

Comment: Mode `"w"` opens a file for writing, but you try to read from it. Even if you open it with `"w+"` for writing and reading there is no `fseek` to be seen repositioning the file pointer to a valid position. Note too: *However, when you switch from reading to writing, the input operation must encounter an EOF marker. If there is no EOF, you must use an intervening call to a file positioning function. The file positioning functions are `fsetpos`, `fseek`, and `rewind`. When you switch from writing to reading, you must use an intervening call to either `fflush` or to a file positioning function.*

Comment: @AyoubSouid even you already accepted my answer I just added a proposal solving the problems, with examples of execution. Bonne continuation ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More than the remarks already did like about `sizeof(&E)` :

In the line

> ```
>    T[i] = E.note;
> ```

you can write out of T, because you never check *i* < 30. For that better to give the size of T (30) rather than to give *fichedeNote* and *E* non initialized in argument.

In the line

> ```
>  if (T[j]>T[j + 1]) {
> ```

you access to the non initialized entry `T[j + 1]` when *j* is `i-1`, or may be out of T is

You read/write the memory representation of Eleve in your file, with the associated little/big endian problem

It seems logic to read the file to put the notes in T *before* to get new notes

---

A proposal :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Eleve {
    float note;
};

size_t lireNotes(float T[], size_t max, const char * fn)
{
  FILE* fichedeNote = fopen(fn, "rb");
  size_t sz = 0;
  struct Eleve E;

  if (fichedeNote == NULL)
    return 0;

  while ((sz != max) && fread(&E, sizeof(E), 1, fichedeNote))
    T[sz++] = E.note;

  fclose(fichedeNote);

  /* debug */
  puts("anciennes notes:");
  for (size_t j = 0; j<sz; j++) {
    printf("Note %d: %.2f\n", (j + 1), T[j]);
  }
  putchar('\n');

  return sz;
}

void saisirNote(float T[], size_t max, size_t sz, const char * fn) {
  char rep;
  FILE* fichedeNote = fopen(fn, "wb");

  if (fichedeNote == NULL) {
    printf("impossible d'ouvrir %s en ecriture\n", fn);
    return;
  }

  do {
    struct Eleve E;

    if (sz == max) {
      puts("plus de place pour une nouvelle note");
      break;
    }

    printf("\nSaisir Une Note %d: ", (sz + 1));
    if (scanf("%f", &E.note) != 1)
      puts("note invalide");
    else {
      T[sz++] = E.note;
      puts("Saisie de note avec Succes !");
    }
    printf("Voulez-Vous Saisir Une autre Note ?: ");
    if (scanf(" %c", &rep) != 1)
      break;
  } while (rep != 'N');

  /* debug */
  puts("\nliste des notes:");
  for (size_t j = 0; j<sz; j++) {
    printf("Note %d: %.2f\n", (j + 1), T[j]);
  }

  /* tri */
  if (sz > 1) {
    int en_desordre;

    do {
      en_desordre = 0;
      for (size_t j = 0; j < (sz-1); j++) {
        if (T[j]>T[j + 1]) {
          float tmp = T[j + 1];

          T[j + 1] = T[j];
          T[j] = tmp;

          en_desordre = 1;
        }
      }
    } while (en_desordre == 1);
  }

  /* debug */
  puts("\n***Note Trie***:");

  for (size_t j = 0; j<sz; j++) {
    printf("Note %d: %.2f\n", (j + 1), T[j]);
  }

  /* update file */
  for (size_t j = 0; j<sz; j++) {
    struct Eleve E;

    E.note = T[j];
    fwrite(&E, sizeof(E), 1, fichedeNote);
  }

  fclose(fichedeNote);
}

int main()
{
  float T[30];
  const char * fn = "/tmp/Fnote.dat";
  size_t sz = lireNotes(T, sizeof(T)/sizeof(*T), fn);

  saisirNote(T, sizeof(T)/sizeof(*T), sz, fn);
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -g -pedantic -Wextra e.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ rm -f Fnote.dat
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out

Saisir Une Note 1: 11
Saisie de note avec Succes !
Voulez-Vous Saisir Une autre Note ?: o

Saisir Une Note 2: 22
Saisie de note avec Succes !
Voulez-Vous Saisir Une autre Note ?: o

Saisir Une Note 3: 15
Saisie de note avec Succes !
Voulez-Vous Saisir Une autre Note ?: N

liste des notes:
Note 1: 11.00
Note 2: 22.00
Note 3: 15.00

***Note Trie***:
Note 1: 11.00
Note 2: 15.00
Note 3: 22.00
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
anciennes notes:
Note 1: 11.00
Note 2: 15.00
Note 3: 22.00


Saisir Une Note 4: 0
Saisie de note avec Succes !
Voulez-Vous Saisir Une autre Note ?: O

Saisir Une Note 5: 44
Saisie de note avec Succes !
Voulez-Vous Saisir Une autre Note ?: N

liste des notes:
Note 1: 11.00
Note 2: 15.00
Note 3: 22.00
Note 4: 0.00
Note 5: 44.00

***Note Trie***:
Note 1: 0.00
Note 2: 11.00
Note 3: 15.00
Note 4: 22.00
Note 5: 44.00
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Note I still use the struct *Eleve*, probably the goal is to add other fields like the name etc

P.S. sorry for non French people, I added messages in French ;-)