# C File Save and Restore input information

Tags: c

I have a program based on a struct with different information.
In this program you can for example add people and delete people etc. I already have all this done, so the program it self is done. But the files are not.

So I am trying to write a code that "saves" if I would for example add a person and this would "save" when I choose to exit the program. And a code that "restores" the people in the file in the beginning of the program.

Does any one have any ideas or tips? I'm new to programming and trying to learn. I have been sitting with this for a few days.
Before I "restore" I ask for an file to open and if this file does not exist a new one is created and this works. So if I would have a file with 3 employees and I would open this file I would want to restore them and then being able to add more employees to the file etc.

Comment: as an example look at my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55050530/i-cant-display-after-i-write-the-table-into-the-filebinary-file it is an example of something similar, even the OP used a 'binary' format I do not recommend

Comment: I see 2 options: First (simple, slow, portable, human readable): using serialize like json. Second (fast): Using `memcpy` to copy structure to bytes(`uint8_t`) and write binary to file in this idea one file => one person.

Comment: @Jo. did you look at the example ? it saves and restores

Comment: As @Jabberwocky stressed, saving and restoring a structure is next to trivial by using C's file functions. The only issue is the `pic` element. Does it indeed point to an array of integer of the size `imageCount`?

Comment: @Matthias If you add a pic the imageCount++ for that exact employee you  added. I mean the program works as it is it is just how to save and restore files.

Comment: @IgorGalczak why "one file one person", what prevents us from writing multiple structs to the same file? And why use `memcpy` and not writing the structure directly from memory?

Comment: @Jabberwocky "one file one person" because we dont how to separate bytes in binary file unless we create some frame to write object. For second you right.

Comment: I upvoted this because i saw research effort,it can be useful for new c programmers and it is quite clear! Do the same if you think it is!

Answer (score 1):

You have to write (and to read) in two steps: first the struct, and then the array the struct points to. 
Code fragment for writing (a.o. without error checking, that is however needed):

```
#include <stdio.h>
// ...
employees emp;
const char* filename="your_filename";
// populate emp;
FILE* file = fopen(filename,"w");
fwrite(&emp,sizeof(employees),1,file);
fwrite(emp.pic,sizeof(int),emp.imageCount,file);
fclose(file);
```

Now you have the array after the struct in your file. Read it in the same way:

```
FILE* file = fopen(filename,"r");
fread(&emp,sizeof(employees),1,file);
emp.pic=calloc(sizeof(int), emp.imageCount); 
fread(emp.pic,sizeof(int),emp.imageCount,file);
```

Please don't forget to check for errors (see `man fopen|fread|fwrite|calloc`). In case you have several structs, you must repeat the two steps for any element.

Comment: Is this possible to do changes to? because I will never just open a certain file, when my program start I get to type in a file name and if it exists it will read in what is in that file otherwise I will create a new file

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand your question, but maybe should check `mode` parameter of `fopen()` (the second parameter). It controls different behaviour in dependence of existence etc.

Answer (score 0):

What is the platform? For Windows there is simple format of `.INI` files with contents like:

```
[Employee_1]
id=123
name=Smith
imageCount=2
...
```

You can use `GetPrivateProfileString`/`GetPrivateProfileInt` and `WritePrivateProfileString` API functions to read and store the information. Use separate section for each employee. One common section is necessary to store the number of employee sections.

Comment: This really is too platform specific.

Comment: I guess Jo. wants working solution not a portable application. The chance to run it on Windows is at least 50% or even more.